# SQLiteException: no such column: 1 (code 1):

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Usually when this problem happens, it's because of missing quotes. But this column is INTEGER, and I'm trying to put an integer value in it. Yet this error pops up:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: 1 (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Artista (id, nome) VALUES (1, '19')`

My code:

```
    String CREATE_TABLE_ORIGEM =
            "CREATE TABLE Origem" +
            "(" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "nome TEXT" +
            ")";

    String CREATE_TABLE_ARTISTA =
            "CREATE TABLE Artista" +
            "(" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "nome TEXT" +
            ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ORIGEM);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ARTISTA);

    String INSERT_ORIGEM = "INSERT INTO Origem (id, nome)";
    String INSERT_ARTISTA = "INSERT INTO Artista (id, nome)";

    String line;
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myContext.getAssets().open("origem.txt"), "UTF-8"));
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                db.execSQL(INSERT_ORIGEM + " VALUES (" + line + ")");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myContext.getAssets().open("artista.txt"), "UTF-8"));
        try  {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                db.execSQL(INSERT_ARTISTA + " VALUES (" + line + ")");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

And those are the txts I'm using to populate the table:
origem.txt: http://pastebin.com/Vk2wHnm5
artista.txt: http://pastebin.com/wfWSbvfR

the funny thing is: the table Origem have an identical format, yet I'm not having any errors in it;

Comment: check the whole query properly!!!!! static or dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text file contains an invisible control character at the beginning (probably an UTF-8 byte order mark). Remove it.

Comment: It was in fact an UTF-8 byte order being inserted by the reader somehow. I added an extra line to the file and made a first call to readLine() before starting to insert the elements in the database

Answer (score 0):

i helped someone out with a similar problem awhile ago. [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729145/error-inserting-data-to-sqlite-database/22729737#22729737) and see if the suggestions might be helpful to you as well.

in short, if you've made DDL changes over time, you may be working with an older version of the schema than you realize:

- if you can, pull down a copy of the DB via DDMS and inspect the schema, or
- try deleting and re-installing the app from scratch to ensure you have the latest version of your schema

hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to clean your app data directly from your AVD or Real Device to "update" your tables.

- Go to Settings -> Apps -> Your App -> Storage -> Clear data.